# Check if a String is contained in an NSDictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, nsdictionary

I am trying to check if an input from a textfield exists in the NSDictionary but I am not sure how to do this.

```
            let nsdict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let values = nsdict?.allValues
```

Once I Do this i am not sure on how to cast the values to a string to check with a user input textfield.

For example doing this:

```
 if values.contains(userIinput.text){
     print("Found")
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your snapshot contains? The format of the data in the snapshot is determined by your Firebase structure as well as if you are observing a node whose value is a String, Int, Bool or possibly another snapshot. Also, are you observing via .value or .childAdded? Adding a snippet of your Firebase structure (as TEXT please, no images) will help us understand the data you are trying to get to and including some code showing how you are reading that data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a filter. In the following code I create a dictionary, and then I filter looking for the *userInput.text*. Every value that matches will get stored in the new dictionary matches. If matches is > 0, the input already exists and you will have a dictionary with the keys that have the userInput.text as value. Also, you can check if it matches more than once.
You need to verify that $0.value is an String or that the userInput is not nil because if the user input is nil and the $0.value of the dictionary is not an String it will be will and return a match.

```
let dict: [String : Any] = ["first" : "String", "Second" : 2]
let matches = dict.filter{ 
              guard let value = $0.value as? String else { return false }
              value == userInput.text 
              }
matches.count
```

If you just want to check if it already exists you can just

```
guard let userInput = userInput else { return }
if (!dict.filter{ $0.value as? String == userInput }.isEmpty) {
    print ("Found")
}
```

In the first example I'm verifying that $0.value is an String if not I am returning that it does not match, and in the second I am checking that the userInput is not nil, if not it finishes the function there (you can use and *if let* if you prefer)

Comment: This can go wrong if `userInput.text` is `nil`. `$0.value as? String` will evaluate as nil if is not an `String` and the comparison will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Gonzo thank you, I have edited the answer to check that the userInput is not nil or to check that the value of the Dic is an String if not, it returns not match.

Comment: Here's the problem. A Dictionary is a key: value pair; if the data read in is a String: String, this code is awesome. However, with Firebase it's common to have that pair be a key: snapshot. This would occur for example, when the code is reading in a /users node (.value) where the key is the uid and the value is a Dictionary of more key: value pairs. That can only be determined if the Firebase structure is known *and* we see how the data is read; either .value or .childAdded. So while this code is good - it doesn't really address the question because there's not enough data *in the question*.